# C++ weird thing

Tags: c++

anyone can explain me, why this parts of code are acting differently?

```
while((c = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 1, f)) != 0);
{
    if(write(t, buf, c) < 0)
    {
        return E_MSGSEND;
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////

do
{
    c = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 1, f);
    if(write(t, buf, c) < 0) 
    {
            return E_MSGSEND;
    }
} while(c != 0);
```

while {} runs only 1time but do {} while 5times. Whats is the difference? Before while {} c is intialized to 1.

Thanks an advice

Comment: Turn on your maximum compiler warning level, and pay attention to the results.

Comment: Please use more descriptive question titles in the future.

Comment: Style conventions and compiler warnings catch this type of error: http://codepad.org/2bicoBiH, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_true_brace_style (there are many more useful warning settings for gcc too, but -Wall -Wextra should be your default in CFLAGS, and use make to build and use that environment variable; similar principle for other compilers)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your first `while`:

```
while((c = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 1, f)) != 0);
```

This in effect makes it an empty loop, which may well execute the same amount of times as the other loop, but its body doesn't include any statements. The following `if`, though, is not part of that loop anymore, so it only executes once.

Comment: Haha, I was about to post about the semantic differences in the two blocks like everyone else did. Good catch, +1

Comment: +1. @Jay: To avoid bugs like this going forward, compile at a higher compiler warning level.

Comment: I should visit some market and watch for new pair of eyes. Thanks a lot. Omg, sorry

Comment: @Jay Welcome :-) Don't make too much of a problem out of it, I believe all of us (including myself) have had similar omissions (or worse). May I ask you to check the answer as "accepted" once you verified that it solved your problem? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the first section, using the `while` loop, you check for EOF or successful read before executing the inner statements.

In the second section, using the `do-while` loop, you don't check for EOF before executing the `if` statement.